# Не отображаются русские символы при использовании Qt в Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, utf-8, locale

Что я пробовала:

**#1:**

```
...
#include <QTextCodec>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QTextCodec* codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
    QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(codec);
  
    ...
}
```

**#2:**

```
QString cyrillicName = QString::fromLocal8Bit("словоНаКириллице");
QString cyrillicName2 = QString::fromUtf8("словоНаКириллице");
```

**#3:**

```
Tools > Options > Environment > Documents > Save documents as Unicode when data cannot be saved in codepage
```

Ничего не работает, пробовала уже и всё вместе, пытаюсь вывести текст в `Message Box`:

```
QMessageBox msgBox;
msgBox.setText(cyrillicName);
msgBox.exec();
```

Вот что получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE:**

Помогло решение с добавлением `#pragma execution_character_set("utf-8")`. Является ли это верным решением?

Comment: Если уж пишите fromUtf8, то и сохранять документ надо в этой кодировке.

Comment: да, это является верным решением.

Comment: Еще можно в настройка Visual Studio разрешить сохранять исходные файлы в utf-8, вы это и так сделали, но затем нужно было выполнить «coхранить как» и выбрать кодировку utf-8.

Дополинтельно, в исходный файл я добавлял комментарий на русском языке, чтоб Visual Studio всегда сохранял исходный файл в utf-8. `#pragma` наверное будет лучше комментария.

Comment: QString(u8"словоНаКириллице");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#pragma execution_character_set("utf-8")
```

Comment: Вы можете отметить этот ответ как правильный, нажав слева галочку.